# How can I user substring to cut content from database using spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, model-view-controller

I'm coding Spring MVC with Hibernate
I've got a string from database use `<%=lGuide.getContent()%>` in `.jsp` file. I want to use substring to cut charaters from 1 to 20 of this content to show Brief Descriptions. Can you show me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Using the JSTL functions you split a string, import the JSTL functions:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

You can use any of the following functions:

```
substring( java.lang.String, int, int)
```

For more details please check [JSTL functions](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html)